# How to use tolower in D

Tags: d, phobos

I want to to put the first letter of a string into lowercase in D.

As a string is imutable in D, there doesn't seem to be a simple way.

I came up with this:

```
string mystr = "BookRef";
string outval = toLower( mystr[0..1] ) ~ mystr[1..$]; 
writeln( "my outval: ", outval );
```

Is there an easier way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While D `string`s are immutable, you can use `char[]` instead:

```
char[] mystr = "BookRef".dup; // .dup to create a copy
mystr[0] = toLower(mystr[0..1])[0];
writeln("my outval: ", mystr);
```

Comment: What would be intuitive? (So that we can suggest to the D devs)

Answer (score 6):

For reference and completeness, you can build this without any allocations by chaining ranges. It has the additional advantages of working with empty strings:

```
auto downcase(string w)
{
    import std.range, std.uni;
    return w.take(1).asLowerCase.chain(w.drop(1));
}
```

[Try online on run.dlang.io](https://run.dlang.io/is/mkZ4ng).

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work with empty strings. https://run.dlang.io/is/ksDBNT.

Comment: Sorry, `dropOne` enforces that the element is actually there, which is why it didn't work with empty strings. Updated the code to use `drop(1)` which essentially does nothing with empty strings.